# While loop running too many times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

EDIT: I figured it out, it was a really obvious error (I used winLoseDraw() instead of a variable I assigned to it...)

I made this code as a challenge to creating a rock-paper-scissors game without using any if statements. For some reason the while loops aren't working (although I've used this kind of code multiple times in C++).

Essentially, if all goes well, the program does this: create an array of all possible combinations ([computer wins] [computer loses] [draw]), an array of
1. get a random number for the computer (could be 0, 1, 2 for rock, paper, scissors).
2. ask the player to enter rock, paper or scissors.
3. create an array of [computer, player].
4. check who wins.

I tried printing, and while it does find the correct combination, for some reason the while loop in winLoseDraw() runs three times.

```py
import random

true = True
false = False
rock = "ROCK"
paper = "PAPER"
sissors = "SISSORS"
possibleHands = [rock, paper, sissors]
possibleCombinations = [ [[paper, rock], [rock, sissors], [sissors, paper]],
                         [[sissors, rock], [paper, sissors], [rock, paper]],
                         [[rock, rock], [sissors, sissors], [paper, paper]]
                         ]
results = ['WIN', 'LOST', 'DRAWED']

def getRandomHandComp():
    x = random.randint(0, 2)
    handComp = possibleHands[x]
    return handComp

def getHandPlayer():
    x = input("please choose: 0 = rock, 1 = paper, 2 = sissors ")
    while (x != '1') and (x != '0') and (x!= '2'):
        x = input("Invalid! please choose: 0 = rock, 1 = paper, 2 = sissors")
    handPlayerNum = int(x)
    handPlayer = possibleHands[handPlayerNum]
    return handPlayer

def winLoseDraw():
    comp = getRandomHandComp()
    player = getHandPlayer()
    match = [comp, player]
    found = false
    number1 = 0
    number2 = 0
    while (not found) and (number1 < 3):
        while (not found) and (number2 < 3):
            found = possibleCombinations[number1][number2] == match
            print(match)
            print(possibleCombinations[number1][number2])
            print(found)
            number2 += 1
        print(found)
        number2 = 0
        number1 += 1
    number1 -= 1
    result = results[number1]
    return [result, comp, player]

gameOver = false
trueFalse = [false, true]
while not gameOver:
    result = winLoseDraw()[0]
    print('COMPUTER PLAYED ' + winLoseDraw()[1] + '!' + 'YOU PLAYED ' + winLoseDraw()[2] + '!')
    print('YOU ' + result + '!')
    x = input("Wanna continue? 0 = yes 1 = no")
    while x != '1' and x != '0':
        x = input("INVALID INPUT! Wanna continue? 0 = yes 1 = no")
    gameOver = trueFalse[int(x)]
```

Here's the output I got:

```
please choose: 0 = rock, 1 = paper, 2 = sissors 1

['ROCK', 'PAPER']

['PAPER', 'ROCK']

False

['ROCK', 'PAPER']

['ROCK', 'SISSORS']

False

['ROCK', 'PAPER']

['SISSORS', 'PAPER']

False

False

['ROCK', 'PAPER']

['SISSORS', 'ROCK']

False

['ROCK', 'PAPER']

['PAPER', 'SISSORS']

False

['ROCK', 'PAPER']

['ROCK', 'PAPER']

True

True

please choose: 0 = rock, 1 = paper, 2 = sissors 1

['SISSORS', 'PAPER']

['PAPER', 'ROCK']

False

['SISSORS', 'PAPER']

['ROCK', 'SISSORS']

False

['SISSORS', 'PAPER']

['SISSORS', 'PAPER']

True

True

please choose: 0 = rock, 1 = paper, 2 = sissors 1

['ROCK', 'PAPER']

['PAPER', 'ROCK']

False

['ROCK', 'PAPER']

['ROCK', 'SISSORS']

False

['ROCK', 'PAPER']

['SISSORS', 'PAPER']

False

False

['ROCK', 'PAPER']

['SISSORS', 'ROCK']

False

['ROCK', 'PAPER']

['PAPER', 'SISSORS']

False

['ROCK', 'PAPER']

['ROCK', 'PAPER']

True

True

COMPUTER PLAYED SISSORS!YOU PLAYED PAPER!

YOU LOST!

Wanna continue? 0 = yes 1 = no
```

I'm suspecting something wrong with random (I already used this kind of code in C++ and it worked as expected if I remember) but I'm not really sure

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can use `print()` to check values in different variables and to see which part of code is executed. You caould also adds some messages in `print()` to better see what you display. OR learn how to use debuger.

Comment: you don't need list `trueFalse`. You can do `gameOver = (x == '1')`

Comment: I just figure it out, it was a really obvious error... I used winLoseDraw() instread of a variable. thanks for replying btw!

Comment: What's this `true = True; false = False` supposted to do there? You are unhappy with the capitalization?

Comment: well I used to program in C++ and I'm used to true and false without capitalization